# Is there any difference between "static NSInteger const" and "static const NSInteger"?

Tags: objective-c

Usually, I have seen the code that to declare constants was just like this:

```
static const NSInteger kNum = 1;
static NSString * const kStr = @"A";
```

I know why `const` should be written behind `NSString *`, but I'm not sure if `static NSInteger const kNum = 1;` and `static const NSInteger kNum = 1;` are same.

Is there any difference between `static NSInteger const` and `static const NSInteger`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are the same. A constant type can be "derived" from a given type by writing one of:

```
const type
type const
```

The order does not matter in this case.

These are a variable pointers to constant data:

```
type const* var
const type* var
```

Which means that the pointer can be changed, but the data can't (unless you cast it). You can read it right-to-left as "pointer to constant *type*".

This is a constant pointer to variable data:

```
type* const var
```

Note the binding.

Which means that the pointer cannot be made to point elsewhere, but you can change the data. You can read that right to left as "constant pointer to *type*".

It will come as no surprise that making both the pointer and the data constant can be done like this:

```
type const* const var
const type* const var
```